# How to stop a python program that is running in the background shell

Tags: python, shell

I have a python program called `main.py` program and I need to run another program in a background shell called `ringToneCheck.py`, so my `main.py` is like this:

```
import os
os.system("python ringToneCheck.py &")
```

but the problem is that when I exit my program with `sys.exit()` command I still have the `ringToneCheck.py` running in shell when I check my running processes.

what should I do to exit and kill `ringToneCheck.py` from my background shell completely??

Comment: Try removing & at the end of command

Comment: use `subprocess` module instead

Comment: when you `import` a module it actually runs it. what you can do is start a thread that imports `ringtonecheck.py` which will then die along with your main program

Comment: There is probably a more idiomatic python way to do this, but be aware that the & at the end tells the operating system to run the command in a new process. Therefore when the main program is terminated, the spawned process stays alive. Removing the & should do it, but like i say, there may be a cleaner way.